# Getting number of IPv6 addresses from Ipv6 CIDR in GO

Tags: go, ipv6

Is there anyway to retrieve the maximum numbers of IPv6 from a CIDR range? Currently I have this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net"
)

func main() {
    ip, ipnet, err := net.ParseCIDR("2001:200:905::/49")
    var ips []string
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    for ip := ip.Mask(ipnet.Mask); ipnet.Contains(ip); inc(ip) {
        ips = append(ips, ip.String())
    }
    fmt.Println(len(ips))
}

func inc(ip net.IP) {
    for j := len(ip)-1; j>=0; j-- {
        ip[j]++
        if ip[j] > 0 {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

But this process runs so slow. Is there any efficient way of retrieving the total number of ip addresses?

Comment: Just a comment: it's almost never interesting to count the number of addresses with IPv6. A single subnet has 2^64 addresses, which is always more than enough. In IPv6 you usually count subnets.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob umm but what do you mean counting the subnets?

Comment: What is it you're trying to do exactly? The number of unmasked bits gives you the number of addresses, so just use that number without counting every possible value.

Comment: As @SanderSteffann pointed out, you will use `/64` subnets (except in a couple of specific circumstances). This gives you `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` possible host addresses per subnet.

Comment: If somebody can show me a case where `18,446,744,073,709,551,616` per subnet is not enough I will send them a big box of stroopwafels! ;)

Comment: I just want to get the starting point of an IP Range and its end ip, so i could transform the start and end into an unsigned int. But anyway, thanks for the answers, I've got a new method to get the start and end without listing all the total ip per range.

Comment: In an IPv6 host subnet, the first address will be `:0:0:0:0` (`::`), and the last address will be `:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff` for the Interface ID. Since IPv6 doesn't have broadcast, you can use all the addresses in a subnet. This greatly simplifies things over IPv4.

Answer (score 1):

The [IPAddress Go library](https://seancfoley.github.io/IPAddress/) can do this (get the count, starting point, end, or any address in the middle) with a few lines of polymorphic code that works with both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.  [Repository here](https://github.com/seancfoley/ipaddress-go). Disclaimer: I am the project manager.

```golang
func details(addrStr string) {
    addr := ipaddr.NewIPAddressString(addrStr).GetAddress()
    lower, upper := addr.GetLower(), addr.GetUpper()
    count := addr.GetCount()
    fmt.Printf("%s has size %d,\n\tranging from %v to %v\n",
        addr, count, lower, upper)
    fmt.Println("\thundredth address is", addr.Increment(100))
}
```

Using your IPv6 example as well as an IPv4 subnet:

```golang
details("2001:200:905::/49")
details("192.168.10.0/24")
```

Output:

```
2001:200:905::/49 has size 604462909807314587353088,
        ranging from 2001:200:905::/49 to 2001:200:905:7fff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff/49
        hundredth address is 2001:200:905::64/49
192.168.10.0/24 has size 256,
        ranging from 192.168.10.0/24 to 192.168.10.255/24
        hundredth address is 192.168.10.100/24
```